# hyperref, toc: Toc links incorrect due maybe to counter reset

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, counters

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Mono}


%% Ensure sequential numbering of subsubsections.
\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\S\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Must not precede the above

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
{\raggedleft\normalfont\small\itshape\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1 
\arabic{paragraph}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{}
        \section*{Beauty}
        \label{sec:beauty}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:beauty}}

        \section*{Preface}
        \label{sec:preface}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:preface}}

    \chapter*{First Grade}
    \label{ch:firstgrade}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:firstgrade}}
        \section*{Introduction}
        \label{sec:intro}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:intro}}
        \section{Outline}
                \subsubsection{Charlie}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}
                \subsubsection{Delta}
        \section{Start}
                \subsubsection{Continue}

    \chapter*{Second Grade}
    \label{ch:secondgrade}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:secondgrade}}

    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{0}

        \section{Declension}
                \subsubsection{Echo}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

The document structure is a bit unusual (it starts on section level, no first chapter specified, and subsubsection numbers run continuously through a chapter), but it is not for me to modify. There are two troubles:

(1) `Echo` ToC entry points to `Charlie`, and `Declension` to `Outline` (intuitive, but still wrong);

(2) `Beauty`, `Preface`, and `Introduction` ToC entries appear nameless and linkless, though `First Grade` and `Second Grade` chapter entries are OK.

Hope there's a way to put things to rights.

Comment: `titlesec` and `memoir`?

Comment: Yes. `\paragraph` title is customized with `\titleformat`, which requires `titlesec`

Comment: Well, `memoir` comes with its own facilities of making structure command format, no need to screw it up with `titlesec` ;-)

Comment: That powerful? Do you care to give me a hint? Preferably in the form of modifying my MWE :) .

Comment: Please test if the example shows the same behaviour without the special fonts and xelatex. If they are not needed to reproduce the issue, remove them from the MWE.

Comment: Your trouble is made by not numbering the chapters. That leave the same link over and over. pdftex/hyperref even warns you about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bookmarks

There are jumps in the section hierarchy:

```
\section{Outline}
        \subsubsection{Charlie}
...
\section{Start}
        \subsubsection{Continue}
```

The level `subsection` is missing. This is not handled well by `hyperref`, but managed by the redesign of the algorithm in package `bookmark`. The package should be added after package `hyperref`, see the example below.

### Unique anchor names

The trouble with the links is caused by anchor names that are not unique.
This is caused by the counter reset. Both counters `subsection` and `subsubsection` are reusing its numbers. But `hyperref` needs unique numbers to
generate the anchor names to generate the link destinations.

Uniqueness can be provided by a proper definition of the companion macros `\theH<counter>` that are used by `hyperref` if they are available. The following example adds a macro `\ChapterAnchorPrefix` to be inserted into
the definitions of `\theH<counter>` for `section` and `subsection`. If a
counter is reset, then `\ChapterAnchorPrefix` must be assigned a new value.

Example (without `titlesec` stuff):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

%% Ensure sequential numbering of subsubsections.
\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\S\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Must not precede the above

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*{\ChapterAnchorPrefix}{chapter}
\def\theHsection{\ChapterAnchorPrefix.\the\value{section}}
\def\theHsubsubsection{\ChapterAnchorPrefix.\the\value{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{}
        \section*{Beauty}
        \label{sec:beauty}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref*{sec:beauty}}

        \section*{Preface}
        \label{sec:preface}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref*{sec:preface}}

    \chapter*{First Grade}
    \label{ch:firstgrade}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref*{ch:firstgrade}}
        \section*{Introduction}
        \label{sec:intro}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref*{sec:intro}}
        \section{Outline}
                \subsubsection{Charlie}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}
                \subsubsection{Delta}
        \section{Start}
                \subsubsection{Continue}

    \chapter*{Second Grade}
    \label{ch:secondgrade}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref*{ch:secondgrade}}

    \renewcommand*{\ChapterAnchorPrefix}{2G}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{0}

        \section{Declension}
                \subsubsection{Echo}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}
                    \paragraph{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Heiko! It works perfectly. The '`titlesec` stuff' is messing things up, indeed. What can I replace it with? I really need to make `10 Exercise` into `Exercise 10` ragged left (flushed right). Is there a clean way to do it using `memoir`?